Celery concurrency vs number of worker
What is the difference between
celery -A tasks worker -l info --concurrency=4

And
celery -A tasks worker -l info -n worker1@%h 
celery -A tasks worker -l info -n worker2@%h 
celery -A tasks worker -l info -n worker3@%h 
celery -A tasks worker -l info -n worker4@%h

If celery uses multiprocess by default, in above 2 cases, does it switches to multithread with --concurrency=4 or it steel uses multiprocess.
Also can someone give me advice to scale my celery configuration. I am new in this, for this reason, i wanted to know what kind of configurations i have with celery to use celery in full power.

         the difference between:  




celery -A tasks worker -l info --concurrency=4  

and
2.
celery -A tasks worker -l info -n worker1@%h  
celery -A tasks worker -l info -n worker2@%h  
celery -A tasks worker -l info -n worker3@%h  
celery -A tasks worker -l info -n worker4@%h  


Answer:
They both are used to run the Celery workers but with much difference in their configuration and behavior. Here is a detailed comparison:

1. Using --concurrency=4:
celery -A tasks worker -l info --concurrency=4

This starts one worker process with a concurrency of 4. The worker will then create 4 internal worker threads or processes (depending on the configuration of the worker pool) to execute tasks concurrently.  Key Points:  All tasks are processed by the same worker instance.

Easier to configure and manage since there is only one worker.  .
Resource allocation (CPU/memory) is shared by a single worker process.  .
It is best for systems where workers share a common state or resources.


2. Starting multiple workers with -n:
 celery -A tasks worker -l info -n worker1@%h
 celery -A tasks worker -l info -n worker2@%h

celery -A tasks worker -l info -n worker3@%h
celery -A tasks worker -l info -n worker4@%h
- **Description:**  
  This starts **4 separate worker instances**, each with its own name (`worker1@%h`, `worker2@%h`, etc.). `%h` dynamically substitutes the hostname.  
- **Key Points:**  
  - Each worker is an independent process and can operate independently.
- More finer grain control over task distribution since each worker is isolated.  - Better fault tolerance: if one worker crashes, others remain unaffected.  - Requires more resources (CPU/memory) because each worker is a separate process.  - Ideal for systems where task segregation or isolation is necessary.

---


| Feature                      | `--concurrency=4`                           | Separate Workers (`-n`)           |
|------------------------------|---------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------|
| Number of Worker Processes   | 1                                           | 4                                 |
| Concurrency                  | Intra-process, controlled by a single worker       | Independent for each worker        |
| Fault Tolerance              | Less robust (single point of failure)    | More robust (independent workers) |
| Resource Usage                 | Lower (shared resources)            | Higher (independent resources)    |
| Task Isolation               | Shared                                      | Independent                       |

-
 When to Use Which? 
Use `--concurrency=4`: 
If you want a more lightweight setup with less resource usage. It is good for small workloads or when it is perfectly safe for tasks to share resources. 
Multiple workers (-n): 
is usually used if you need stronger fault tolerance or task isolation.
- For larger workloads where resource separation is important.       


There is a huge difference between the two.
celery -A tasks worker -l info --concurrency=4

The command above will start a "Celery worker" (that is how they call it in the documentation - very confusing) in the default (pre-fork) concurrency mode. Celery worker process will spawn four worker-processes that will execute tasks.
However,
celery -A tasks worker -l info -n worker1@%h 
celery -A tasks worker -l info -n worker2@%h 
celery -A tasks worker -l info -n worker3@%h 
celery -A tasks worker -l info -n worker4@%h

will create four Celery worker processes. Each of them will run in the default (pre-fork) concurrency mode, and each will spawn N worker-processes to execute tasks. Now, imagine you run this on machine with N=8 cores. - You will end up with 32 worker-processes!
